# ImportError: cannot import name 'YamlModel' from 'pydantic_yaml'

Tags: python, yaml, python-import, blender, pydantic

I am working at blender script, where I want to use YAML. So I try to import it:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic_yaml import YamlModel
```

But when I run my script, this error will occure:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'YamlModel' from 'pydantic_yaml' (C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\lib\site-packages\pydantic_yaml\__init__.py)
```

I have installed `pydantic` and `pydantic_yaml` on both Pythons (Blender one and the common one), if they wouldn't be installed, there would be different error. I tried googling, but google had very few results for this problem. Also, when I open that `__init__.py` file, there is clearly `YamlModel`. Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: Fixed in v0.9.0 https://github.com/NowanIlfideme/pydantic-yaml/releases/tag/v0.9.0

Answer (score 0):

I found the same error and it is related how pydantic-yaml got installed.

There is a bug in the package. you need to install optional dependencies as well (so called extras).

```bash
pip install pedantic-yaml[pyyaml,ruamel]
```

or manually install `pyyaml` `ruamel` please make sure that that Taumel version is <=0.18

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for me.

Comment: I run into the same problem and for some reason it didn't work for me immediately either. After rebuilding the environment and installing latest pydantic, pydantic-yaml and PyYAML it started working. I'd suggest to rebuild the environment.

Answer (score 0):

YamlModel is removed in version 0.10.0. You can install 0.9.0 by pinning version like below:

```
pip install pydantic-yaml==0.9.0
```